# PHP- input form.get text area

Tags: php, forms

Why i can't send throw a form a word with spaces like 'Exemple PHP'.For sending information i use post.I have tried to do this issue whith get but i have the same issue.
The code for form is :

```
<form action='modifica_contact.php' method=\"post\"  id=\"id_modific\">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"emailModifica\" value=".$info['email'] .">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"numeModifica\" value=".$info['nume_complet'].">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"telefonModifica\" value=".$info['telefon'].">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"facultateModifica\" value=".$info['facultate'].">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hobbyModifica\" value=".$info['hobby'].">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"websiteModifica\" value=".$info['website'].">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"descriereModifica\" value=".$info['descriere'].">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"orasModifica\" value=".$info['oras'].">
        <button type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"id_modific\"> Modifica </button>
    </form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this being `echo`ed with php?

Comment: You need to wrap you `value` values in quotes as well -> `value=\"".$info['email'] ."\"`, `value=\"".$info['nume_complet']."\"`, etc., and since you are building your form in php, the quotes will need to be escaped `\"`. Without the quotes, your form will only send the first word, breaking on the space.

Comment: You could use `'` as your attribute quoting (as you did with `action='modifica_contact.php'`) so you don't have to escape a bunch of `"`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT an answer, Is a comment about HTML generation in PHP.

More about how to use PHP to generate HTML. Rather than staying in PHP mode at the start of the script and 'ECHO'ing large amounts of HTML, with lots of escaping of the various styles of 'quotes'. Which is rather easy to get confused with.

Switch in and out of PHP mode as required.

Here is the 'switching version' of the above form:

```
<form action="modifica_contact.php" method="post"  id="id_modific">
        <input type="hidden" name="emailModifica" value="<?= $info['email'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="numeModifica" value="<?= $info['nume_complet']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="telefonModifica" value="<?= $info['telefon']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="facultateModifica" value="<?= $info['facultate']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="hobbyModifica" value="<?= $info['hobby']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="websiteModifica" value="<?= $info['website']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="descriereModifica" value="<?= $info['descriere']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="orasModifica" value="<?= $info['oras']?>">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="id_modific"> Modifica </button>
</form>
```